# Programming automations in iOS to edit appearance of photos

Tags: ios, automation, sirishortcuts

I love how powerful some of the iOS Shortcuts and automations features are, but can’t find any programming options to edit the visual appearance of a photo.

I would like to add a shortcut to the Photos app share menu so that I can specifically:
• Select multiple photos
• Go to the shortcut menu and run my shortcut/automation which will:
• Change filter to “Vivid” 50%
• Add Vignette 20%
Then save changes to all photos.

Is this possible in one shortcut/automation? Thank you!

NB - you can run automations that resize images or convert to another format, but I can see nothing to edit the actual appearance of a photo within the Photos app. I don't want to apply any filter 100% which I'm aware you can do as a default directly from the Camera.